# How to print first column as a string in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have 1 file(called letters) like this:

```
a i
d u
b k
```

The program takes one mandatory argument, the file name(letters.key). It needs to read this file using a **while read from to** loop and output everything in column 1 as a string, then space, then everything in column 2 as a string.
So for the above example it should print: **adb iuk**

This is my code so far:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        // need to figure out this part
else
        echo "Incorrect number of arguments passed"
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: So your code so far does not even attempt to read from the given file. You should find out how to read a file line by line and maybe write an intermediate version of you script that outputs the values as they are read.

Answer (score -1):

run the awk script

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[i]=a[i]$i}} END{for(i in a){print a[i]} print "\n"}' letters.key
```

for readability

```
awk '
BEGIN{ORS=" "}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    a[i]=a[i]$i
  }
} 
END{
  for(i in a){
    print a[i]
  };
 print "\n"}
' < letters.key
```

Answer (score -1):

bash

```
col=()
while read a b; do
    col[1]+=$a
    col[2]+=$b
done < letters
echo "${col[*]}"
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? Popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to. Thanks!